# How do I write a loop that gives an array with elements in the form of mathematical functions using python language?

Tags: python, loops, math

I have an array F = np.array([0.00,1.77*10**7,1.97*10**7,1.67*10**7,0.00])

I want to write a loop that gives a new array with elements in the form of mathematical functions like this: f(x) = F[i] - x
F[i] is the elements of list F

Comment: You don't need a loop. Please have a look the Numpy basics: https://numpy.org/doc/1.21/user/absolute_beginners.html#broadcasting

Comment: What should I do when someone answers my question? stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Decide if the answer is helpful, and then... - Vote on it - Accept it

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Solution **with loop**:

```
math_array = []
x = 5 # insert value x as desired.
for v in F:
  math_array.append(v - x * v)
math_array = np.asarray(math_array)
```

**2.** You can do it **cleaner and faster without a loop**:

```
F = np.asarray([1,2,3,4])
x = 5
result_array = F - x*F
```

**Result:**

```
array([ -4,  -8, -12, -16])
```

Thanks to the ability of Numpy to do arithmetic operates elementwise:
More examples here:
[Elementwise Numerical operations on arrays](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `x` is given,

```
final = []
for i in len(F):
   final.append(F[i] - x * F[i])
```

OR

```
final = []
for num in F:
   final.append(num - x * num)
```